# Getting values from Data Tables and pass to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, datatables

I'm having problems on how to get data from data tables into modal form. this is my php code for the data tables:

```
$cTableBody .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.date('m/d/Y',strtotime($date_created)).'</td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editMyReservation"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteMyReservation"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
```

and my modal form is this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editMyReservation" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        EDIT RESERVATION
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="create-date" class="control-label col-sm-3">Date Created: </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="disabledInput" disabled/>
                                </div>

                        </form>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">SAVE</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have no idea on how to pass the values.

Comment: You are using laravel and inline php? I recommend you start reading up on [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [templating using blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade).

Comment: @Luceos yeah im starting the laravel. but for now im not using it for my testing...

Comment: Edited* removed the laravel tag

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you can get the values using javascript, and pass the values to php through AJAX.